# Set orientation with viewDidAppear

Tags: ios

I've overridden an initial app view's navigation controller so that the view is set to load in portrait mode and not rotate (other views in the app do rotate to display both portrait and landscape views- but this initial one doesn't.):

```
@implementation CustomNavigationController

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // return NO;
    // Return YES for supported orientations
     return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait);
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
    // Return a bitmask of supported orientations. If you need more,
    // use bitwise or (see the commented return).
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    // return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation) preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    // Return the orientation you'd prefer - this is what it launches to. The
    // user can still rotate. You don't have to implement this method, in which
    // case it launches in the current orientation
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}
```

This works great on initial load, my problem is however that within the app other views can potentially be seen in landscape orientation. If a user visits one of these landscape views and then returns to the initial app home page form this view then the initial home page gets brought into view in landscape orientation (I need this to always be in portrait.)

Is there a way to force the initial view to return to portrait orientation with viewDidAppear always return the view to portrait orientation?

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: You can check current device orientation and set home page to portrait orientation no need to view didappear method

Comment: I have already set the home page to portrait orientation (ass above code) however this doesn't seem to work when returning to this view from another view displayed landscape orientation.

Comment: Is there a known solution to this?

Comment: nope, afraid that doesn't work

Comment: Hey @user1419810, what if you change it to return `YES` in `shouldAutorotate` function?